# How do I execute a class function in another file?

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I'm trying to call a class function that will write some text to a console window in Tkinter.

However when I try to run it. I am getting the below error.

```
TypeError: write() missing 1 required positional argument: 'txt'
```

Here is my full code:

main.py

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory
import os
import nam


class Window(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master = None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.init_window()


    def init_window(self):
        self.master.title("Source Data Checker")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        self.pathLabel = Label(text='Select the location of the source data below and press "Generate Excel"')
        self.pathLabel.place(x=110, y=40)

        self.selectFolderButton = Button(self, text='Select Folder', command=self.openfile)
        self.selectFolderButton.place(x=180, y=350)

        self.executeButton= Button(self, text='Generate Excel', command=self.run)
        self.executeButton.config(state=DISABLED)
        self.executeButton.place(x=330, y=350)

        self.outputWindow = Text()
        self.outputWindow.place(x=100, y=80)
        self.outputWindow.config(width=50, height=15)

    def openfile(self): #open the file
        self.directory = askdirectory()
        if self.directory != '':
            nam.panels_count(self.directory)
            self.executeButton.config(state=NORMAL)
            print(nam.a_nam)

    def run(self, txt):
        pass

    def write(self, txt):
        self.outputWindow.insert(END, str(txt))
        self.update_idletasks()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("600x400")
    app = Window(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

nam.py

```
from main import *

def panels_count(folder):

    Window.write('test')
```

I was thinking I may need to instantiate it. But when I do that, The program won't even run.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5):

You need to call the method *on an instance*. You are calling it on the class, at which point there is nothing for `self` to be bound to, so  `Window.write('test')` expects *two* arguments but doesn't have a value for `txt`.

The `openfile` method has access to the instance via `self`; pass that in to the other function:

```
def openfile(self): #open the file
    self.directory = askdirectory()
    if self.directory != '':
        nam.panels_count(self, self.directory)
        self.executeButton.config(state=NORMAL)
        print(nam.a_nam)
```

and

```
def panels_count(app, folder):
    app.write('test')
```